# How to get Editor value in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with React js and I am using Next js. Right now I am trying to get value of "Editor" but giving me following
error:

```
"TypeError: editor is null"
```

Where i am wrong? How can i fix this? Below is my handleSubmit function.

```
const handleSubmit = async(e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let editor: any = null;

         <Editor
            onInit={(evt, ed) => {
              editor = ed;
              }}
            initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor.</p>"
            init={{
              height: 500,
              menubar: false,
              plugins: [
                'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
              ],
              toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | ' +
              'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
              'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
              'removeformat | help',
              content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
            }}
      />

       const content = editor.getContent();
        alert('content is ' + content);
};
 return (
    <>
 <form className="forms-sample" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>        
        <Editor />
<button type="submit" className='btn btn-primary mr-2'>Submit </button>
);
```

Comment: It would be worth including what kind of editor are we talking about? Is it written by you? Is it a library?

Comment: @BalázsÉdes its library (tinymyce )